# Eigen Conversion invalid matrix template parameters

Tags: eigen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run the Darpa Arm Robot in electric, has anybody else tried this?

The install [instructions](http://www.thearmrobot.com/trac/wiki/ARMSimulatorInstallation) are given only for cturtle, but from a bit more reading I believed that the incompatibility with diamondback and electric had to do with converting from eigen2->eigen3.

After a few code changes, I have got all but one package to build, BarrettCompat.

Has anybody else run into this sort of error?

```
In file included from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:299:0,
                 from /home/phil/devel/arm_simulator/stacks/darpa_arm_sim_servers/BarrettCompat/include/barrett/systems/../systems/../math/matrix.h:22,
                 from /home/phil/devel/arm_simulator/stacks/darpa_arm_sim_servers/BarrettCompat/include/barrett/systems/../systems/../units.h:123,
                 from /home/phil/devel/arm_simulator/stacks/darpa_arm_sim_servers/BarrettCompat/include/barrett/systems/../systems/wam_specs.h:4,
                 from /home/phil/devel/arm_simulator/stacks/darpa_arm_sim_servers/BarrettCompat/include/barrett/systems/exposed_output.h:39,
                 from /home/phil/devel/arm_simulator/stacks/darpa_arm_sim_servers/BarrettCompat/src/barrett/ExposedOutput-specializations.cpp:1:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h: In static member function ‘static void Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::_check_template_params() [with Derived = Eigen::Matrix<double, 7, 1, 1, 7, 1>]’:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:304:7:   instantiated from ‘Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols>::Matrix(const Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols>&) [with _Scalar = double, int _Rows = 7, int _Cols = 1, int _Options = 1, int _MaxRows = 7, int _MaxCols = 1, Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols> = Eigen::Matrix<double, 7, 1, 1, 7, 1>]’
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/phil/devel/arm_simulator/stacks/darpa_arm_sim_servers/BarrettCompat/build'
/home/phil/devel/arm_simulator/stacks/darpa_arm_sim_servers/BarrettCompat/include/barrett/systems/../systems/../math/detail/matrix-inl.h:145:23:   instantiated from ‘barrett::math::Matrix<R, C, Units>::Matrix(const barrett::math::Matrix<R, C, Units>&) [with int R = 7, int C = 1, Units = barrett::units::JointPositions<7>, barrett::math::Matrix<R, C, Units> = barrett::math::Matrix<7, 1, barrett::units::JointPositions<7> >]’
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/phil/devel/arm_simulator/stacks/darpa_arm_sim_servers/BarrettCompat/build'
/home/phil/devel/arm_simulator/stacks/darpa_arm_sim_servers/BarrettCompat/src/barrett/ExposedOutput-specializations.cpp:12:53:   instantiated from here
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/phil/devel/arm_simulator/stacks/darpa_arm_sim_servers/BarrettCompat/build'
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:615:7: error: ‘INVALID_MATRIX_TEMPLATE_PARAMETERS’ is not a member of ‘Eigen::internal::static_assertion<false>’
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12556/eigen-conversion-invalid-matrix-template-parameters/) by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 682 on 2012-01-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) on 2012-01-17**:
yep, thanks... note the author date/time ;-)

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-01-17**:
quick google on the error yields: http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=98536

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The compilation errors mentioned were solved
[here](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=98536&p=210774#p210774)

The Dashboard UI runs, but there are still errors running the controllers and loading robot models into gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) with karma: 682 on 2012-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) on 2012-01-10**:
That's fair, although I should really ask separate questions, one relating to the Eigen conversion and a larger question about an up-to-date darpa arm sim stack.

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2012-01-10**:
marking question as answered as it appears you have found your solution for the Eigen errors posted in the original post